# Asp.net Ajax toolkit auto complete extender not calling a web service using asp.net C# and also progress bar image

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Web services code is working properly, but in text box not fetching data from a database. And no error displaying.

Web Service Code:

```
/// Summary description for WebService

/// </summary>

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, 

uncomment the following line.

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]     

 public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {

  public WebService()
  {


   //Uncomment the following line if using designed components

  //InitializeComponent();

  }


 [WebMethod]

public List<string> GetCountries(string prefixText, int count)

{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from auto_txt where name like @name+'%'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", prefixText);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    List<string> ListNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ListNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
    return ListNames;
} }
```

Design Code Default.aspx:

```
    <div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"     EnablePartialRendering="false">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"  >
   </asp:TextBox>

    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCountry" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="0" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="20" UseContextKey="True" OnClientPopulating="ShowProcessImage" OnClientPopulated="HideProcessImage" >
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
```

Java Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProcessImage() {
        var autocomplete = document.getElementById('txtCountry');
        autocomplete.style.backgroundImage = 'url(loading1.gif)';
        autocomplete.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        autocomplete.style.backgroundPosition = 'right';
    }
    function HideProcessImage() {
        var autocomplete = document.getElementById('txtCountry');
        autocomplete.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the use of count parameter in GetCountries()?

Comment: If I remove count parameters then also not fetching data from database.

Comment: Put breakpoint at List<string> ListNames = new List<string>(); this line and check the value of dt and index of your Country Name column. I suggest to use columnname instead of index like [1] in for loop. I mean use something like dt.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString() instead of dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().

Comment: But Webservice Code is working perfect. I am not unable to fetch data into textbox using  auto complete extender.

Comment: If you have Mozilla then install firebug addon.. its free. After installing run your webpage on in mozilla. Open Firebug by pressing F12. Open net tab in it. GO to All Tab. refresh your page. now type 2-3 characters in text box. See if your webservice is being fetched and called properly. Check the request and response. You can verify the errors in Console tab if any.

Comment: i got error like TypeError: Sys.Extended is undefined. @Captainsac